Tighter upper bound for $ \|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p $ when $ \Delta $ is on a $ p $-norm unit ball
I am interested in proving a left tail bound on $ \|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p $, where:

$ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^k$ sampled from a Generalised Gaussian Distribution, i.e., pdf proportional to $$
\exp\left(-\left(\frac{\|\mathbf{x}\|_p}{\sigma}\right)^p\right)
$$,
$ \Delta \in \mathbb{R}^k $ on a $ k $-dimensional $ p $-norm unit ball, i.e., $ \|\Delta\|_p \leq 1 $,
$ 4 \leq p \leq \log k $ that is an even integer

This leads me to first proving an upper bound for $ \|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p $ that is more easily to be analysed.
In general when $ \Delta \in [-1, 1]^k $, one can prove the following bound:
$$
\|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p \leq p \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i + 1)^{p-1}.
$$
By symmetry of Gaussian we can assume $ \Delta $ has all negative entries, so
$$
\|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p = \sum_{i=1}^k \left( (x_i - \Delta_i)^p - x_i^p \right),
$$
which is equal to to:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \int_{x_i}^{x_i - \Delta_i} p y^{p-1} dy \leq \sum_{i=1}^k \int_{x_i}^{x_i - \Delta_i} p (x_i - \Delta_i)^{p-1} dy \leq p \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i - \Delta_i)^{p-1} \leq p \sum_{i=1}^k (x_i + 1)^{p-1}.
$$
Question
Given that $ \Delta $ is now on $ p $-norm unit ball rather than $ [-1, 1]^k $, is it possible to obtain a tighter upper bound for the expression $ \|\mathbf{x} - \Delta\|_p^p - \|\mathbf{x}\|_p^p $?
Any guidance on how to approach this problem or references to related work would be greatly appreciated.
